# Frontend Mentor Password Generator App using react js and typescript, strength meter problems

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am doing a frontend mentor challenge which is a password generator that has a range slider, 4 checkboxes and a strength meter.
The problem that I am having is the strength meter.
In the challenge that I am trying to match, there is a strength meter which is  69.7px width that contains 4 individual bars which are 10px wide and 28px high with a 8 px gap between each bar.

for too weak strength, the first bar should be red with 3 empty bars
for weak strength, the first and second bars should be orange with 2 empty bars
for medium strength, the first, second and third bars should be orange with 1 empty bar
for strong strength, all four bars should be filled.

I can get the bar container, the bar sizes but the color depending on strength fills the background of the bars.
If I hover over the bars with the dev tools, the individual bar inside the bars container is showing transparent but the color of the strength is showing. It should be the bar coloured and the container and unfilled bar that should be transparent.
Could somebody please suggest how I could fix this so that only the individual bars are either colored or transparent.

```
Strength Meter Component
import zxcvbn from "zxcvbn-typescript"

type PasswordStrengthMeterProps = {
  password: string
}

const PasswordStrengthMeter = ({ password }: PasswordStrengthMeterProps) => {
  const passwordScore = zxcvbn(password).score
  const states = [
    { items: ["too-weak"], id: "too-weak", label: "too weak!", color: "red" },
    { items: ["weak"], id: "weak", label: "weak!", color: "orange" },
    { items: ["medium"], id: "medium", label: "medium!", color: "yellow" },
    { items: ["strong"], id: "strong", label: "strong!", color: "green" },
  ]

  const { id, label, color } =
    states[passwordScore] || states[states.length - 1]

  return (
    <div className='password-strength-meter'>
      <span className='label'>{label}</span>
      <div className={`bars ${id}`}>
        {[...Array(4)].map((_, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`bar ${
              index < passwordScore ? color : "transparent"
            }`}></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PasswordStrengthMeter


css
.password-strength-meter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--clr-secondary-400);
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  margin-block: 1rem;
}

.label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.32rem;
  color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid 2px white;
  width: 69.7px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--clr-secondary-400);
}

.bar {
  height: 28px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 2px lime;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.too-weak {
  background-color: red;
}
.weak {
  background-color: orange;
}
.medium {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.strong {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I have tried taking the .too-weak, .weak, .medium, .strong background colors out but the bars were empty, only the outline shows.
i have tried removing the color from the states but that didnt work.
I don't know how to fix this.